# Display google favicon and entity in img source in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, object, layout

looking for solve my issue.
i do a edit on a laravel site, but i cant call back the site url (entity.toUrl) for add to the "img src" with a google favicon.

i need to change the "imageIconUrl" with the "toUrl"

actual situation:

```
<a target="_blank" class="entity-url" :href="entity.toUrl">
<img :src="entity.imageIconUrl" :alt="entity.title">
<span>@{{entity.toUrl}}</span>
</a>
```

i try to edit from:

```
<img :src="entity.imageIconUrl" :alt="entity.title">
```

to (removed : before src and change to entity.toUrl):

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=@{{entity.toUrl}}" :alt="entity.title">
```

or:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{$toUrl}}"
```

but now if i check on site the source of the favicon image i get back this url:

```
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{entity.toUrl}}
```

and not

```
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com
```

when i call it in the   `<span>@{{entity.toUrl}}</span>` work but not in the img src

any suggestion for help me?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your scenario, but assuming `entity` 
is a variable being passed on to your view from the controller, you may try the following:

```html
<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{$entity->toUrl}}" :alt="entity.title">
```

note there is no "@" before the {{...}} and the variable should be prefixed with $.

If you want to use `title` from `entity` in the image alt, it should work in the same way:

```html
<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{$entity->toUrl}}" alt="{{$entity->title}}">
```

Note that I am not an expert - just another newbie looking for solutions here. :)

good luck!

Comment: many thanks for reply, i try your suggestion but i get back a 500 error on load. i check the log and i see: "Undefined variable: toUrl" . not understand why work for <span> but not for the <img src>